# Exec command insertText isn't working as expected on facebook.com

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, execcommand

This is a contenteditable element that you can create posts on facebook.com

[image]

All I want is inserting text into that contenteditable while keeping the new lines.

```
document.execCommand("insertText", false,"a sentence with \n\r a new line")
```

is not working, it just stripes `\n` and `\r` as we saw in the screenshot:

[image]

I have tried `insertHTML, insertParagraph` commands but no luck.

I have seen that they append a `<br/>` element when I press "Enter", so I also tried to append a `<br/>` element but it doesn't work

Changing `.value, .textContent, innerHTML, innerText` is not working as well.

I can't provide a MRE as it's a protected route.

Comment: HTML doesn't know `\n\r`, you've to insert `br` element.

Comment: @Teemu I've tried it too. I guess they re-render their content editable element as I append a child into their element and I can't even see my appended element there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert it in lines and manually dispatch the <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> key in-between:

```js
function insertText(text, elem = document.querySelector('[contenteditable=true]')) {
  elem.focus();
  for (let i = 0, lines = text.split(/\r?\n/); i < lines.length; i++) {
    // send a dummy keyCode:0 first to initialize the editor's React state.
    elem.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {keyCode: i && 13, shiftKey: true}));
    document.execCommand('insertText', false, lines[i]);
  }
}
```

Then call it as `insertText('foo\nbar')`